# PHP For Loop, Compare Incrementing Value to Incrementing Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

- Short question: I am trying to see if a variable `($y)` is *between* multiple array values from a database (`$ending[0] && $starting[0], $ending[1] && $starting[1]`, etc...). "**If**" `$y` is between any of those, `echo "statement"`.

I'm using a for loop to increment a drop down in *30 minute* intervals from *9am - 7pm*.

If any of those times = a time saved within my database, it echoes "*not available*" instead.

Now I need to see "**if**" the dropdown time is "*between*" the start and end times in the database and make those "not available" as well.

Everything works if I manually identify which array keys to compare...but my question is: can I check the drop down value against all of the values in the arrays?

Example:
Start Dropdown: 09:00am 09:30am 10:00am etc up until 07:30pm. End Dropdown: 09:30am 10:00am 10:30am etc. up until 08:00pm. If there is a start and end time of 09:00am(start) 10:00am(end) saved in the database for an appointment, the dropdown will show "Not available" for the corresponding starting and end times, so a user cannot double book an appointment. What I am asking about, is how to identify all of the "in between" values...09:30am for example, cannot be a start or an end time, if the 09:00am-10:00am slot is already booked.

```
$sql_slots = "SELECT * FROM XXXXX WHERE date = '$query_date' ORDER BY XXXXX ASC";   

    $result_slots = mysqli_query($connection, $sql_slots);  

    $open = strtotime("9:00am");

    $close = strtotime("9:30am");

    $starting = array();
    $ending = array();

            while($row_result_slots = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_slots)){   

                $starting[] = $row_result_slots['start_time'];

                $ending[] = $row_result_slots['end_time'];      

                }

    echo'
    <select name="start_time">';

        for($b = 0; $b <= 20; $b++){

            $y = strtotime(($b*30) . " Minutes", $open);

            $the_time = date("h:ia", $y);

            // Here, instead of only comparing the first values in the array, I need to match it up against $ending[1] & $starting[1], $ending[2] & $starting[2], etc... 

if(in_array($the_time, $starting) || ($y <= strtotime($ending[0]) && $y >= strtotime($starting[0]))){
                echo "<option>Not Available<br></option>";
                } else {
                echo "<option>" . $the_time . "<br></option>";
                }
            } 

        echo'</select>';
```

Comment: Could you show us what the select is going to look like with some dummy data for start and end?

Comment: Start Dropdown: 
09:00am 
09:30am 
10:00am 
etc up until 07:30pm. 

End Dropdown: 
09:30am 
10:00am 
10:30am 
etc. up until 08:00pm.

If there is a start and end time of 09:00am(start) 10:00am(end) saved in the database for an appointment, the dropdown will show "Not available" for the corresponding starting and end times, so a user cannot double book an appointment. What I am asking about, is how to identify all of the "in between" values...09:30am for example, cannot be a start or an end time, if the 09:00am-10:00am slot is already booked.

Comment: First you should edit the question with that information. Second, what is the normal length of an appointment. Last, why is the start time concerned with the end time?

Comment: There are 3 different types of appointments, which makes it a pain...1hr 30mins, 1hr, and 30mins (Tax Return, IRS Audit Services, Free Consultation). The start time and end time, together, represent the appointment timeframe. To be able to allow users to book their own appointments, I need to block out these timeframes. To do that, I am checking to see if the start time or end time match ones already in the database, then also checking to see if the selected time falls between a start and end time, and blocking those out too. I'll update my question with the other info.

Comment: This works, but I figure isn't the most "efficient" way of doing it: if(in_array($the_time, $starting) || ($y <= strtotime($ending[0]) && $y >= strtotime($starting[0])) || ($y <= strtotime($ending[1]) && $y >= strtotime($starting[1])) || ($y <= strtotime($ending[2]) && $y >= strtotime($starting[2]))|| ($y <= strtotime($ending[3]) && $y >= strtotime($starting[3])))

Comment: Have you looked at my provided answer?

Answer (score 0):

How about that?

```
$sql_slots = "SELECT * FROM XXXXX WHERE date = '$query_date' ORDER BY XXXXX ASC";   

$result_slots = mysqli_query($connection, $sql_slots);  

$open = strtotime("9:00am");

$close = strtotime("9:30am");

$reserved = array();

        while($row_result_slots = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_slots)){   

            $start = $row_result_slots['start_time'];

            while ($start <= $row_result_slots['end_time']) {

                $reserved[$start] = true;

                $start = date("Y/m/d h:i:s", strtotime($start . "+30 minutes"));
            }
        }

echo '<select name="start_time">';

    for($b = 0; $b <= 20; $b++){

        $y = strtotime(($b*30) . " Minutes", $open);

        $the_time = date("h:ia", $y);

        if(isset($reserved[$the_time]){
            echo "<option>Not Available<br></option>";
            } else {
            echo "<option>" . $the_time . "<br></option>";
            }
        } 

    echo'</select>';
```

Comment: The logic behind it makes sense. Something about this is making the loop continuously run and not load the page though. I fixed some missing ")" and ";" before doing so, but it's still continuously looping.

Comment: which loop has the problem. I don't have your data set

Comment: make sure that the date format in `$reserved` match the data format from your database. Use an `echo` + `break` in the `while` that populate the array.

Answer (score 0):

Below is what I came up with. This uses a `do while` loop and creates a `reserved` array that will fill all time between what is given in the appointment.

I updated the data to use my own array but updated your `mysqli` work with what should be correct. If not I left in my testing code for you to view if needed. I also used the `disabled` `attribute` on an `option` over outputting some text.

```
<?php
$sql_slots = "SELECT * FROM XXXXX WHERE date = '$query_date' ORDER BY XXXXX ASC";   

$result_slots = mysqli_query($connection, $sql_slots);  

$open = strtotime("9:00am");

$close = strtotime("7:00pm");

$space = 900; //15min * 60 seconds space between? 
              //This seems more normal for people to see.

//Simulate these appoinments
/*
$query_results = array(
    array(    
        "start_time" => "9:00am",
        "end_time"   => "9:30am"
    ),
    array(    
        "start_time" => "10:30am",
        "end_time"   => "11:30am"
    ),
    array(    
        "start_time" => "11:45am",
        "end_time"   => "12:30pm"
    )
);
*/
$reserved = array();


while($row_result_slots = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_slots)){ 
    //**NOTE**: Make sure these are times or use strtotime()
    $next_slot = $reserved[] = strtotime($row_result_slots['start_time']);
    $end_time = strtotime($row_result_slots['end_time']);

    while($next_slot < $end_time){
        $next_slot += $space;
        $reserved[] = $next_slot;
    }
}
/*
foreach($query_results as $appoinment) {

    $next_slot = $reserved[] = strtotime($appoinment['start_time']);
    $end_time = strtotime($appoinment['end_time']);

    while($next_slot < $end_time){
        $next_slot += $space;
        $reserved[] = $next_slot;
    }
}
*/
echo'<select name="start_time">';
$current = $open;
do {
    $disabled = in_array($current, $reserved) ? 'disabled' : '';
    echo '<option ' . $disabled . '>' . date("h:ia", $current) . '</option>';
    $current += $space;

} while($current <= $close);

echo'</select>';
```